# What is the cheapest way to build power lifting fitness room for one person?

Tags: powerlifting

[image]

As I imagine this is:

- one barbell, aprox 1,000$ with pancakes up-to 400kg.
- two dumbbells, up-to 80kg each.
- one bench.
- one rack for squats.
- plus rubber covering for floor.

As I can see, it is very expensive pleasure. More than 1,000$.

Is there way to cheapening ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised to where you are, what you can afford, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding the non-powerlifting and other extraneous elements of my home gym, I spent a whole lot less than your plan. Here's how.

- Craiglist squat rack: 300 dollars. Took two weeks for the posting to appear. (NB: I sold the rack for just under that amount, 2 years later. Not bad.)
- Cement floor. Piece of scrap plywood for deadlifts.
- Barbell and 300 pounds of plates, found on craigslist, circa $150

I don't use a bench because I don't bench, but used benches are cheap cheap cheap and making it yourself doesn't sound that hard either.

How can you make your plan cheaper? Well, decide for yourself. Buying new is expensive. Buying 400kg worth of weight is expensive. Buying gear you don't need is expensive.

Comment: 150kg + barbell for 150$ ? Is it normal barbell ? Could you share full link to craiglist with right place?

Comment: @ConcealmEnt Yeah it was a real barbell. Craigslist is just used stuff. It's region-specific and time-sensitive so there's no way to link to it. You've just got to look for used gear.